# Verificar se determinado valor já existe em uma tabela SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

Estou tentando verificar se determinado valor já esta ou não inserido na minha tabela. Exemplo : Verificar ser determinado Imei já existe na coluna DeviceImei.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Estou tentando fazer um select count, para retornar 0 caso o Imei não esteja inserido na tabela. Exemplo:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Porem isto não esta funcionando, está me retornando o erro : A converção do valor varchar '352093084525269' causou l'overflow de uma coluna int.

Obs: A tabela se chama AVL_Ignition e o campo DeviceImei é um varchar .

Gostaria de saber se utilizar o select count é eficiente ? Também gostaria de saber qual é a causa deste error ?

Comment: parece q o erro está no `where`, o campo DeviceIMEI deve ser texto, já tentou `where DeviceIMEI = '123'`?

Comment: @Ricardo Pontual já havia tentado, porém com aspas duplas. Acabei de tentar com aspas simples e deu certo. Obrigado pelo tempo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solução**:

Como dito pelo Ricardo Pontual nos comentários, é necessário colocar aspas no **123**

---

**Explicação**

Ao comparar dois tipos diferentes, é feita uma conversão implícita.

Como dito na [documentação](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-precedence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017):

> Quando um operador combinar duas expressões com tipos de dados diferentes, o tipo de dados com a precedência mais baixa será convertido no tipo de dados de maior precedência.

Conforme essa mesma documentação, a ordem de precedência do `varchar` (352093084525269) é menor que do `int` (123), portanto o SQL SERVER tenta converter o valor do `DeviceIMEI` para `int`.

Como o limite do int (2.147.483.647) é menor que o valor do DeviceMEI (352.093.084.525.269), ocorre o erro de overflow do `int`.

Colocar o *123* entre aspas faz com que seja lido como varchar, evitando essa conversão.